# Parse a C Output map using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I'm currently struggling to parse an C Output.map File using regex.
I'm treating each line separately:
A single line could look like this

```
__func_name     |00010d88|   T  |              FUNC|00000010|     |.text
```

> Expected Output:
>   1) "__func_name"
>   2) "00010d88"
>   3) "T"
>   4) "FUNC"
>   5) "00000010"
>   6) (empty string)
>   7) ".text"
>   8) (empty string)

However the number of white spaces between the texts varies:
Another line could Look like this:

```
__func_name2|0007bb7c|   T  |              FUNC|00000034|     |.text    sourcefile.c:49
```

1) "__func_name2"
2) "0007bb7c"
3) "T"
4) "FUNC"
5) "00000034"
6) (empty string)

7) ".text"

8) "sourcefile.c:49"

As you can see not only the number of white spaces varies, but there is also the source file listed.
Now i did try to solve this Problem using the regexr.
I basically need the following requirements for my regex

1. Alphanumeric string
2. A (hex)Number
3. A single letter
4. A String
5. A (hex)number
6. An optional string
7. Another optional string

Each Group is separated by a `|` character.
I tried this regex. Although incomplete, regexr tells me that I'm only matching the first group.

Could you help me to figure out what's wrong with my regex?

```
([__A-Za-z0-9])\w+|((([\|]{1})&[0-9a-h]&([\|]{1})))\w+|([A-Z])\w+
```

You can try a live demo here:
https://regexr.com/4gpvf

**Edit: Expected Outputs added**

Comment: It seems rather obvious that `|` is being used as a delimiter.  Wouldn't it be far simpler to split by that, then trim each resulting string?  The last segment would be `.text    sourcefile.c:49`, and that can be easily parsed with a *much* simpler regex.

Comment: What output would you expect in your second example - would you expect the source file to be part of the final string, two separate strings or the source file omitted?

Comment: Do  you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/BFDygW/1

Comment: hm split is a good idea. Do you mean like this? ```string[] single_element = single_line.Split((char)('|'));``` ?

Comment: Just `single_line.Split('|')`.  I would not remove empty columns if you want to preserve the column indices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions seem to be unnecessary, yet if no option exists, this expression:

```
(__[^\|\s]+)\s*\|([^\|\s]+)\s*\|\s*([A-Z]+)\s*\|\s*([A-Z]+)\s*\|([^\|\s]+)\s*\|\s*\|([^\|\s]+)\s*(?:([^:]+)?\s*:\s*?([0-9]+))?
```

might collect our desired values, and ignores the spaces and pipes, and there is an optional group for sourcefile here:

```
(?:([^:]+)?\s*:\s*?([0-9]+))?
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5v6ajX/1/)

#### Example

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"(__[^\|\s]+)\s*\|([^\|\s]+)\s*\|\s*([A-Z]+)\s*\|\s*([A-Z]+)\s*\|([^\|\s]+)\s*\|\s*\|([^\|\s]+)\s*(?:([^:]+)?\s*:\s*?([0-9]+))?";
        string input = @"__func_name2|0007bb7c|   T  |              FUNC|00000034|     |.text    sourcefile.c:49

__func_name     |00010d88|   T  |              FUNC|00000010|     |.text";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: very nice work. Thx a lot ! (I'd vote for you but Looks like i do not have enough Reputation)

Answer (score 1):

A rather simple match pattern could be this:

```
@"\s*(\S*)\s*\|\s*([a-f0-9]+)\s*\|\s*(\S)\s*\|\s*(\S*)\s*\|\s*([a-f0-9]+)\s*\|\s*(\S*)\s*\|\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*).*"
```

Executed this way:

```
  string[] data = 
  {
    "__func_name   | 00010d88 | T | FUNC | 00000010 |     |.text",
    "__func_name2 | 0007bb7c | T | FUNC | 00000034 |     |.text    sourcefile.c:49"
  };

  var matchess = data.Select(s => Regex.Matches(s, @"\s*(\S*)\s*\|\s*([a-f0-9]+)\s*\|\s*(\S)\s*\|\s*(\S*)\s*\|\s*([a-f0-9]+)\s*\|\s*(\S*)\s*\|\s*(\S*)\s*(\S*).*", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));

  foreach (MatchCollection matches in matchess)
  {
    foreach (Match match in matches)
    {
      foreach (Group group in match.Groups)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(group.Value);
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main()
{
    var x = @"__func_name2|0007bb7c|   T  |              FUNC|00000034|     |.text    sourcefile.c:49";
    var matches = Regex.Split(x, @"\s*\|\s*");
    int len = matches.Length;
    int i = 0;
    for (int z = 0; z < len; ++z)
    {
        ++i;
        if (z == len - 1)
        {
            var match = Regex.Match(matches[z], @"^(?i)(?'text'\.[a-z]+)(\s+(?'file'[a-z]+\.[a-z]+:[0-9]+))?$");
            WriteLine($"{++i}) {match.Groups["text"].Value}");
            WriteLine($"{++i}) {(match.Groups["file"].Length == 0 ? "" : match.Groups["file"].Value)}");
        }
        else
        {
            WriteLine($"{z+1}) {matches[z]}");
        }
    }
}

/* Output:
    1) __func_name2
    2) 0007bb7c
    3) T
    4) FUNC
    5) 00000034
    6)
    8) .text
    9) sourcefile.c:49
*/
```